# my form validation is not working properly for select box in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, drop-down-menu

i am working on form validation in codeigniter i create a validation rules for my form in My Controller. I have two select box and i want to validate both now the problem is both the select box show the same error message i want to show different message for each select box.

The main problem is the error message will show the same error of city for both select box..  i want different error message for different select box.

and One More question ::  when i get a validation error message for any one field the whole form is got empty. i want to show like that when i got a validation error for any field the other field data will be there.

This is my Controller:

```
public function addEmployeeController()
{

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $abcd = $this->input->post('city_id');
    $abc = $this->input->post('desi_id');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_jdate', 'Joining Date', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_addr', 'Address', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_sal', 'Salary', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_descr', 'Description', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'trim|required|min_length[10]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city_id', 'City', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desi_id', 'Designation', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate');



    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->index();         
    }

    else
    {           


        if($query = $this->Emp_model->addEmployeeModel('$data'))
        {
            $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
            $this->load->view('emp_view', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('emp_view');          
        }
    }

}

public function select_validate($abcd)
{
        // 'none' is the first option that is default "-------Choose City-------"
        if($abcd == "none")
        {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'Please Select Your City.');

                return false;
        } 
        else
            {
                // User picked something.
                return true;
            }
}

public function select_validate1($abc)
{
        // 'none' is the first option that is default "-------Choose City-------"
        if($abc = "none")
        {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'Please Select Your Designation.');
                return false;
        } 
        else
            {
                // User picked something.
                return true;
            }
}
```

And in View i have the select box  like this. when i submit the form without selecting the select box it show the error message of "Please Select Your City"
for both select box. I want to show different message.

```
<p>
    <lable for="desi_id">Designation:</lable><?php echo form_error('desi_id'); ?>

        <select name="desi_id">
        <option selected="selected" value="none">Select Post</option>   

        <?php foreach ($records as $row) { ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $row->desi_id ?>"><?php echo $row->post_name ?></option>
        <?php } ?>


        </select>

    </p>
```

City:
        
            Select City

            
            city_id?>">city_name?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello for your different message you need to define:

**For Message :**

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_jdate', 'Joining Date', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_addr', 'Address', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_sal', 'Salary', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_descr', 'Description', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emp_mobile', 'Mobile Number', 'trim|required|min_length[10]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city_id', 'City', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('desi_id', 'Designation', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate1');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('city_id', 'Your message');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('desi_id', 'Your other message');
```

**For empty other fields :**
You have to use set_value('field_name') in all fileds.

```
<input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo set_value('city'); ?>" />
```

**Your minor mistake :**
callback_select_validate **and** callback_select_validate1

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city_id', 'City', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('desi_id', 'Designation', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate1');
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: your second solution is working ...  but  1st has still show an error like "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Designation.(select_validate)"

Comment: as you give me the solution for message it's not working . i change set_message field  as you show.  you see i use two separate function for both message in controller.  and thanks for second solution.

Comment: no only second issue : For empty other fields                                                                   this solution for Message is not working.

Comment: ok you defined the set_message in other functions(that is select_validate and select_validate1). But try to define that after you defined all rules.

Comment: see my edited code and remove that two functions(that is select_validate and select_validate1)

Comment: ok i do what you say sir...   delete the function and put the set_message under validation rule...  still got the same error.

Comment: make sure your input name is city_id and desi_id

Comment: Okei put that functions agin as it is and i have checked your code properly u have call_back same function in city and desi. see this (callback_select_validate) where u set the rules.

Comment: ya but that's for the select box validation. they may have to be same for select box type.   and if i change what i should i write there instead of that. the rules are may have same for same type.

Comment: ok for city_id field you want display message like "Please select you city" ? and for desi the message should be "Please select your desi" Right ??

Comment: OK i got but you called same function where you set the rules for city_id and desi_id. for city_id ($this->form_validation->set_rules('city_id', 'City', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate')) that is perfect. But for desi_id it should be ($this->form_validation->set_rules('desi_id', 'Designation', 'trim|required|callback_select_validate1')) callback_select_validate1 so select_validate1 function should be call for desi.

Comment: Thanks....  sir...  i got it...   and thank you very much. kindly stay connected for more questions. again thanks.

Comment: solved now? if yes then accept my answer so it will help others... and vote it up :)

Comment: yes sir i accepted the answer and vote it up...  thanks again sir. you made my day. thx   :D

Comment: sir got a problem in the validation..  now when i submit the form the error of designation field is still come and stop my form to submit...   i select the value form designation select box  but it show the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83929/discussion-between-deep-parekh-and-ankit-suthar).

Comment: Sir @Deep Patekh... can you give me your skype id or email...  my email id is   --  ankitgate1@gmail.com